# gpu-z 2.43.0 is showing 8-pin #1 voltage as 20.4 V for Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060. is it normal?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, power-supply, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

[image: gpuz-screenshot]

gpu-z 2.43.0 is showing 8-pin #1 voltage as 20.4 V for Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 6GB version. I use the gpu in my LENOVO LEGION 5 PRO   --  82JQ0062IN -- laptop. i thought the voltage should be 12 volts. is it normal?

Comment: If it is a laptop then anything goes for the power rails... chances are that it is the charger voltage and for some reason that rail got connected to the GPU input voltage sense, possibly so that the GPU can detect when on mains and so go up to a higher power state. Does it change when on or off charge by any chance?

Comment: when external power supply is plugged in it shows 20.4 volts, when on battery it shows 16.7 volts.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is probably normal, and while the "8 Pin Voltage" on a desktop computer would normally be 12V, there is no reason to have that specific voltage present in a laptop, it is simply a generic "easy" voltage to have in a desktop that is using 240 or 120V mains. You have to come down from mains voltage to *something* and 12V is just a standard voltage used.

The main voltages present in a laptop will be the battery voltage (in your case ~16.7V) and a handful of other voltages for USB the CPU and other devices. exactly 12V in a laptop would be surprising. It appears that your GPU takes in whatever the incoming power is and then uses it to created the the "Main" PWR_SRC voltage for your GPU that according to your graph is 10.4V.

As a result that voltage sense line can be slightly repurposed and may well be being used to give your GPU an indication of whether it is on the charger (20V) or the battery (16.7V). This would allow the GPU to switch performance profiles depending on power source.

When on battery it would likely reach a lower peak clock speed and could ramp up speed slower and ramp down faster to conserve battery.

When on mains it would ramp up faster to a higher clock speed because there are no real power constraints.